# setcookie() working on localhost but not working on production (domain.com)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, setcookie

I have been facing some issues regarding `setcookie()` in php. `setcookie()` is working fine on local host
but not on live domain. here's how i am setting in localhost.

**Localhost**

```
   setcookie("private_token",$jwt,$expire_claim,"/","",false,true);
```

**Domain**

```
   setcookie("private_token",$jwt,$expire_claim,"/","domain.com",false,true);
```

**Ajax Call**

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/api/userAPI.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (res, text, code) {

             if (code.status == 200) {
                 window.location.replace("landing.php");
             } else {
                 alert("something went wrong");
             }
        },
        error: function (res) {
            if (res.status == 401) {
                alert("failed to authorize");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Header's in PHP**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

P.S: i think i have already searched entire site. but haven't found anything regarding this matter

**Edit:**
These are the lines before `setcookie` . these are excuted after setting header which i already mentioned earlier

```
 SELF::$connection = Parent::getConnection();
    $str = "select * from user where col=?";
    $query = SELF::$connection->prepare($str);
    $array = array($user->__get('col'));
    $query->execute($array);
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $session = new session();
        $session->set_session($row['id']);
        $id = $row["id"];
        $username = $row["user"];
        $password = $user->__get("pass");
        $email = $user->__get("mail");
        $hash = $row['pass'];
        if(password_verify($password,$hash))
        {
            $secret_key = "dummy";
            $issuer_claim = "THE_ISSUER"; // this can be the servername
            $audience_claim = "THE_AUDIENCE";
            $issuedat_claim = time(); // issued at

            $expire_claim = strtotime('+1 day', $issuedat_claim);; // expire time in seconds
            $token = array(
                "iss" => $issuer_claim,
                "aud" => $audience_claim,
                "iat" => $issuedat_claim,
               //u "nbf" => $notbefore_claim,
                "exp" => $expire_claim,
                "data" => array(
                    "id" => $id,
                    "username" => $username,
                    "email" => $email
                ));
```

now i just got following error in response

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at <file directory where setcookie has been called>:74) in <b><file directory where setcookie has been called></b> on line <b>77</b><br />
```

line 74 `"expireAt" => $expire_claim`

line 77 `setcookie("private_token",$jwt,$expire_claim,"/","domain.com",false,true);`

Comment: In what way is it "not working?" Are you seeing the `Set-Cookie` response header? Do you see the cookie in your browser storage? Also, this may just a typo in your post, but it looks like the cookie name is different between your local and production sites. Do you actually have different code between them or just configuration?

Comment: Yeah i have been checking console. In Application tab then cookies tab. I am newbie to "headers" thing. I'll fix that typo.
What am i expecting in set-cookie in response header?

Comment: In the response headers you should see one(or more) headers with the key `Set-Cookie` and the value as the string defining your cookie(like you would see in JavaScript), if PHP is actually setting it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: Where is this setcookie called? Can you give us all the lines of code that is above this line?

Comment: I would also check your logs. A common mistake is to send output early which prevents additional headers from being sent. This should trigger a warning.

Comment: @Andreas `setcookie` is called right after database verification. there's a huge piece of code above this line. In Short **password verify** then **$jwt token generation** and then this line come's in.Is there any other way to share a piece of code with you?
@akenion

Comment: As I see it then there is no way to properly help you since any output, notice or error will make setcookie not work.

Comment: @akenion there is only one warning from fontawesome. is there any other way to send that to you ?

Comment: @KingMax I am referring to the PHP log, not the JavaScript console, to be clear. If you have any relevant logs, add them to your question. @Andreas is likely right and as I mentioned before the issue is likely that output is being sent early preventing headers from being sent. This is commonly caused by things like line breaks after closing PHP tags. If you have anything writing output prior to the `setcookie` call(without output buffering), this will not work.

Comment: @Andreas i have post my functions.. database functions are being called after setting headers in different php file

Comment: @akenion well i am trying to get error_logs but somehow i can't find error_log file. I'll let you when i find that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setcookie` is failing to actually set the cookie because the headers have already been sent. Cookies are set in HTTP responses using the `Set-Cookie` header.

You have PHP script outputting content prior to your `setcookie` call. Without seeing your entire project, it is not possible to identify exactly where. Typically the cause of this is having files saved with extra characters after closing PHP tags at the end of a file(this is a common problem). You will need to locate and remove these extra characters(assuming they are extraneous). Otherwise, you will need to refactor your logic so that `setcookie` can be called earlier.

The only other option would be to enable [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). This will prevent the output from being sent immediately; it will be buffered in memory and send when the request is complete unless you explicitly send it earlier. This is useful in various cases, but would really only be a workaround for the root problem here.

In your case, since this is happening only in one environment, I would start with reviewing any environment specific code/configuration(which it sounds like you have). It may also be your deployment/build process is adding extra characters when deploying to the problematic environment.

Comment: Yeah actually i was outputting response before `setcookie`.
Outputting response after `setcookie` solved the problem. Thanks. Learnt something new :)